# VBA Excel-How to work with cancel button in the MS Excel close?

Tags: excel, events, vba, messagebox

I am running a macro while in `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)`
but whenever user clicks on **Cancel** button macro should not run.

---

I kept following lines of code

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Cancel = True Then
    MsgBox "You clicked on Cancel"
ElseIf Cancel = False Then
    Call SDA
End If
```

End Sub
But whenever i press **Cancel** button it is not showing me any MessageBox.Any help would be appreciated greatly.[image]

Comment: The `Cancel` argument does not say weather cancel was pressed. It lets your code overide the close event that is happening, setting it to true will stop excel from closing the workbook, leaving it alone or setting it to false will allow the close action to complete.

Comment: @NickSlash, Is there anyway to find whether the `Cancel` is pressed or not? thaks for reply:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this please:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim Msg As String
Dim ireply As Integer
    If Not Me.Saved Then
        Msg = "Do you want to Save this book? "
        ireply = MsgBox(Msg, vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)
        Select Case ireply
            Case vbYes
                Me.Save
                Call SDA 
            Case vbNo
                Me.Saved = True
            Case vbCancel
                Cancel = True
                MsgBox "Cancelling...workbook close event!"
                Exit Sub
          End Select
    End If        
End Sub
```

- Output dialogs:

[image]

The usual structure of a messagebox cancel event wrap is as follows:

```
'--Display MessageBox
    Dim intMsg as integer
    intMsg = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo, strTitle) 
    '--Check pressed button
    If iRet = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "NO!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Yes!"
    End If
```

Comment: @Saikiran please take a look at the first one. It's literally `over-writing` the usual `Close_Before event`

Comment: @bonCondigo,hi thanks for your response, but it doesn't work for me.`let me tell you my requirement in an another way: I just want to dispaly MessageBox when user clicks on CANCEL button`.

Comment: @SaiKiranMandhala it seems work for me, when I click on the cancel button.. Let me update the screen.. :)

Comment: @bonCodigo 's first example does exactly that? It wont be possible (or easily possible) to hook when the cancel button is pressed in the standard excel message box.

Comment: You could also change `iResult` to `Dim msgRes as VBMsgBoxResult`and deal with the enumeration directly. I'm not a huge fan of VBA's implicit conversions so I try to avoid casts and converts that automagically happen in the code as much as possible. There isn't anything wrong with what this solution says though.

Comment: @bonCodigo, can we disable the Excel's standard closing MsgBox?

Comment: @SaiKiranMandhala What do you mean by the standard closing MsgBox? You need a messagebox to click on either save, no or cancel. So this is not the standard, this is overriding what you are getting :) Have you tried this one? your first request was *that you wanted to show a message after clicking on cancel button* and this does it..

Comment: @bonCodigo, yeah i tried it works fine for **Cancel** but if i go with **No** again i am getting one more dialogbox which is coming from inbuilt excel dialogbox, but i don't want it at nay moment.:-(

Comment: @SaiKiranMandhala that's weird, coz I don't get it when I click on `No` with the same code.. Try to `supress` the `DisplayAlerts` at the `No` case then...

Comment: @bonCodigo, I am really sorry it was my macro which is again firing dialogbox. Now it is ok. It worked like a charm. Thanks a lotttt:-)

Comment: @SaiKiranMandhala oh don't be sorry :) you got to know the scenario well now :) Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: This sample will break auto save functionality when you press "Don't save" on your custom dialog...